# How to do MindSphere App Automation Testing with Postman or Newman?

Tags: postman, newman, mindsphere

Mind App Automation Testing with Postman or Newman possibility?

Is there a mechanism to login to a MindSphere Tenant in Postman??

Exposing access token via API in a mind app in the same tenant and using it in subsequent Rest API calls is another option which I am not looking for.

https://developer.mindsphere.io/howto/howto-local-development.html says two options. But,

1) Access tokens generated using service credentials have admin scope, which means it is not suitable for testing applications with different user types.

2) Session cookies are only valid for up to 12 hours and expire after 30 minutes of inactivity. However, by assigning your user specific application roles it is possible to test your application's behavior for users other than admin. Is there a way to avoid this copy paste sessions for complete automation??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this moment, there is no known solution for this. But you can try this:
Use selenium to login in a headless chrome and get session cookies and XSRF Token and store them in environment. Then attach them in API calls.

This is what I am doing at this moment. Let me know if you come to know any other solutions/suggestions.